# Div getting hide behind flash content

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show a previous and next `div` over flash content which is opening in iframe.I have tried all the `wmode=opaque` or `wmode=transparent` or `wmode=window`, but fail to work in IE8.

I can't add because flash content is coming from other site. I am loading the other site in `iframe`.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: The iframe itself, not flash object within, covers your div.

Answer (score 3):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pjgxt/2/

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="controls prev">prev</div>
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/PbsaHzIokEE" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
    <div class="controls next">next</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.controls {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: lime;
    z-index: 10;
}

.prev {
    left: 50px;
}
.next {
    right: 50px;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

### Notes

- **`z-index`** controls the layering of elements.
- You can only apply a
  `z-index` to elements that have a **`position`** of `relative` or
  `absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

try it with giving `z-index` property to div